# How to link to different div in div

Tags: php

I want to change the area which responds as a link. The page output is a grid of circles with my team members in it. Currently the text which appears when hovering over with my mouse is clickable, i want to change it to the whole inner circle. The piece of code where it is stated is as follows:

So the div sc_team_member_inner needs to link in stead of sc_team_member_name.

Sorry for the very basic PHP question.. Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
if ( $members->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $members->have_posts() ) {
        $members->the_post();
        ?>
        <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" class="sc_team_member">
            <div class="sc_team_member_inner">

                <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
                    echo the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' ) ;
                else {
                    echo '<img src="' . SC_TEAM_URL . 'inc/img/noprofile.jpg" class="attachment-medium wp-post-image"/>';
                }
                ?>

                <?php if ( 'yes' == $this->options[ 'name' ] ) : ?>
                    <div itemprop="name" class="sc_team_member_name">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" class="<?php echo $this->check_clicker( $single_template ); ?>">                            
                            <?php the_title() ?>
```

Comment: _"Sorry for the very basic PHP question"_ - this isn't a PHP question. You have a client-side problem, so only client-side code is relevant. So please show that, and create a [mcve].

Comment: You need to use Javascript to make things other than anchors act as links.

Comment: You want to make it so that the whole image is clickable, correct? Not just the link that shows up on hover? Basically making it so that the image is clickable, and reacts as a link? If so, you put a link inside the container, and set it as `display: block;`, removing any padding on the container-element. Add height/width as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what I think you want?

```css
.sc_team_member_name {
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.sc_team_member_name a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
a:hover {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div itemprop="name" class="sc_team_member_name">
  <a href="link_to_person" rel="bookmark"> </a>                           
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I meant, the class of team_member_inner needs to link to the page of the specific teammember. I will try to figure it out and let you know if i got the wanted result. Thanks!